# What "throttled concurrency" means in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, cloudbees

CloudBees says that a free application gets 128M of RAM and "throttled concurrency". Can someone explain what exactly does it mean?

Comment: You have a link to notion of throttled concurrency?

Comment: It means nothing in Java itself, it is probably more related to how CloudBees implements their service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't from a Java page, but it still seems to explain the concept quite well.

> The concept of “concurrency control,” or more appropriately, “throttling concurrency,” refers to the number of threads that are allowed to do work at a particular time in the ThreadPool; it’s a policy to decide how many threads can be run simultaneously without hurting performance.

- From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx) site.

It seems that `throttling concurrency` is a practice whereby we limit the amount of possible active threads at one time. This practice, counter-intuitively, can actually help to increase throughput. [This website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things5/) is about Java, but I feel it doesn't explain the concept as well.